# Como obter 'identificador único' do navegador

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, id

Em minhas pesquisas já encontrei o *Object - navigator*, para obter as informações pertinentes ao navegador do usuário.

Entretanto não achei nada satisfatório nesse *navigator* que eu posso usar juntar para gerar um identificador único desse navegador, para poder armazenar(DB) e reconhecer em um futuro acesso(permitir/negar).

*Resumindo*: Tem que ser único para cada navegador (ex: Token, MD5).

> Senhores, possuem alguma sugestão? ou é algo que está bem diante dos
>   meus olhos e não vi?

Comment: No front-end nada será satisfatório, tudo pode ser manipulado e mesmo que existisse, não seria confiável pelos motivos que citei e se alguém lhe disser/responder que é possível fazer no front-end desconfie... Talvez o que você precise é criar uma sessão no back-end e mante-la com cookies (quase todas linguagens e/ou frameworks web fazem isso).

Comment: Exatamente como o @GuilhermeNascimento disse, o front-end pode ser manipulado. Tem [uma excelente resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37477928/3388148) no SOen, porém é como ele disse, não é seguro. (Se quiser eu posso transcreve-la aqui)

Comment: https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2

Comment: O que você quer está relacionado a COOKIE.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, especialmente ao _Sorack_ e _GabrielKatakura_, por me mostrar a existência do fingerprint, agora tenho uma excelente base para continuar meu projeto. Sobre a imutabilidade desse fingerprint é o de menos, pois o recurso de registrar o navegador é apenas para usar o CDN do servidor(ex: faz o login via cli/navegador e apartir dai aquele 'meio-de-acesso' estará autorizado [podemos dizer grosseiramente que o fingerprint vai ser o two-factor da app]);

Comment: @GuilhermeEscarabel fingerprint é para analisar o passo a passo do usuário não? Será que isso tudo não é um canhão para matar formigas? O que você quer me parece que é algo bem mais simples.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Você chegou na centelha da minha ideia. A princípio seria para fins de registro bem como você disse, entretanto, quis ser mais audacioso. Não gosto da forma padrão de autenticação. Resumindo minha ideia: "Usuários tem que realizar a autenticação para poder pedir permissão que aquele meio de comunicação possa ser usado para consumir os endpoints-protected(independente se for chave sincrona ou assincrona)". Esta minha abstração se der realmente certo será _open-source_ para mostrar como podemos mudar a forma de pensar a autenticação comum e chegarmos a meios mais ponderados.

Comment: @GuilhermeEscarabel uma coisa é simplesmente autenticar, outra é analisar os passos do usuário, analisar os passos talvez dependa da autenticação, mas não ao contrário, é tornar complexo o que deveria ser fácil, não concorda? A não ser que seja uma aplicação quase completa, mas neste caso a história muda totalmente de figura.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento É uma aplicação completa, não envolve apenas usar o navegador e fazer alguns CRUD's, o espaço não permite explicar, mas envolve: commits, stream, command-line. A autenticação nessa aplicação é e deve ser checada a cada 2 segundos. Por isso é que utilizo um servidor a parte para atender estas checagens(com tratamento de limite de request-per-user). Se você diz que é inviável/complexo, compreendo sua preocupação e talvez minha pessoa esteja pensando de forma errada, vou analisar melhor até onde isso será realmente necessário. Mas não vejo uma rota alternativa até então.

Comment: Não sei o tamanho da complexidade, mas vejo tantas formas de burlar isso que não sei se vale a pena.

Comment: A resposta mas plausível que consigo encontrar para sua pergunta seria utilizar cookies já que cada browser terá os seus próprios e você juntaria com algum hash e teria seu identificador único.

Answer (score -4):

Uma solução seria utilizar o ip + cookie dependendo da tecnologia utilizada e muito viável esse tipo de autenticação.